# How to clear dataGridView rows from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms Form1 and Form2, Form 1 with a dataGridView and a button where Form2 has one button.

When i click the button1 in Form1, it will open Form2 (overlapping).

> Now i need to clear ***the values of the datagridview in Form1 when i press the
>   button in Form2*** also the same button click event should close the
>   Form2.

Any idea how to do it?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I use Form1.Close(); but the instance is closed before dataGridView.Rows.Clear(); executes... and i don't know how else to do this...

Answer (score 3):

**This is Form 2:**

```
private DataGridView _dgv;

public Form2(DataGridView dgv)
{
    _dgv = dgv;
    InitializeComponent();
}


private void buttonClearRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _dgv.Rows.Clear();
     Close();
}
```

**This is Form1:**

```
 private void buttonOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   new frm2(dataGridView1).ShowDialog();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference to Form1 into Form2, either by consctructor or by a property. Sample uses constructor. Change the names of the controls to the ones you have. Consider this as a pseudo code sample.

**Form1** (some logic removed for brewity)

```
public class Form1
{
   ...
   public void Clear() 
   {
       DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
   }

   public void btnOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      var form2 = new Form2(this); // create a new form2, and pass a reference to form1
      form2.Show(); // show the form.
   }
   ...
}
```

**Form2** (some logic removed for brewity)

```
public class Form2
{
   private Form1 _parent; // this will hold the parent until Form2 is disposed.
   ...
   public void Form2(Form1 parent) 
   {
       _parent = parent; // assign Form1 instance to a field.
   }

   public void btnClearGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      _parent.Clear(); // clear the rows in the datagridview instance within form1.
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: No instance in the object reference... is there any other way than this one? cause all the answer here leads to one same error....

Comment: Can you update the question with some code? Maybe the block where you get that exception?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, I strongly suggest to hide access to DataGridView in Form1 from outside the class, to avoid unexpected behavior in future.

You could instead add a function in **Form1** and manage button1 click event in this way:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 dialog = new Form2();
        dialog.ShowDialog(this);
    }

    public void ClearRows() { dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); }
}
```

Then in **Form2** you can easily handle click on button in this way:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Form1)this.Owner).ClearRows();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simply, in the form1 you can create an instance of Form2 and after the show you can set the reference of dataGridView in child form2.

**Fundamental is who you set the dataGridProperty modifier=public(visual property F4) in the form1**

This is Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.dataGridViewPassed = this.dataGridView1;
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

This is Form 2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public DataGridView dataGridViewPassed = null;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridViewPassed.Rows.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this everytime Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Comment: are you sure your codings are right? in form1 "this.Form1DataGridView" is throwing errors... i change it to "this.dataGridView1" if the above mentioned error occurs then the method itself is not working, there is no instance of form2...

Comment: @AccountUnknown You're getting that error because the `myDataGridView` is not related to the `DataGridView` in Form1. Hence the "Object" is null

Comment: @KTOV please take look at scheien's answer exactly under Form2 _parent.Clear(); in the button click event that is where my problem is...

Comment: @AccountUnknown Regarding schein's answer, try _parent.myDataGridView.Clear();

Comment: @KTOV Clear(); is the method defined in form1, scheien is calling it from form2... if i am right... The problem is that the instance is not passed on to form 2 that's why it's empty...

Comment: @AccountUnknown He's not calling anything from Form2, he's calling Form2 from Form1 and passing the DataGridView

Comment: I modify the code, I hope you can try this with succes.
This code run.
Before my code was an example for idea.